# Varying Data Type error SSIS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am having an issue with a SSRS report cell that is aggregating 2 fields for me, using the same code. There is a mixed data type error here, I believe because of the 0 and use of `"-"` I have the report to run for different months and oddly enough I am only seeing a #ERROR for two of my months. I've tried adding conversions throughout the code but it doesn't seem to fix it. Can anyone help point out why I am receiving an #ERROR in my aggregates?

`=IIF(Sum(Fields!ID30activity.Value + Fields!ID60activity.Value + Fields!ID90activity.Value) = 0, "-", Sum(Fields!ID30activity.Value + Fields!ID60activity.Value + Fields!ID90activity.Value))`

The warning I am receiving from SSIS:

> Warning   2   [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox523.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.

Answer (score 1):

Okay well a bit of trial and error solved this for me, I added CDEC( in front of both SUM portions to fix this:

`=IIF(Sum(CDEC(Fields!ID30activity.Value + Fields!ID60activity.Value + Fields!ID90activity.Value)) = 0, "-", Sum(CDEC(Fields!ID30activity.Value + Fields!ID60activity.Value + Fields!ID90activity.Value)))`